# SSRS Subscriptions - Email to variable email address

Tags: reporting-services, subscriptions

I'm fairly new to SSRS and I've been assigned to create a subscription. I understand how they are created, but I'd like to have the address field be a variable, versus hard-coding the addresses.

So basically in my report, I generate a list of help desk items to be assigned. Few fields include date, assigned technician, and technician's email address.  I would like to set up the subscription so that if a help desk item is assigned to that technician, email just those individuals (get the email from the dataset and place it in the subscription email address box. Is this possible?

Is there going to be programming involved? I do have some knowledge of ASP.NET/VB.Net; currently using 2010 Ultimate for developing and Visual Studios 2008 for SSRS.

Thanks for any help.

K~ru

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a [Data-Driven Subscription](http://bit.ly/quUtT7)
One of the things it allows you to do is provide a dataset as the list of email address to be sent to, so for UserA is runs for and sends them an email (granted their email is in the database) and then same thing for UserN and so on.